# Not able to send email usign sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail

I don't have a local SMTP server installed, but I heard sendmail command can do the  favour for me, but seems I encountered a problem...

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -v foo@example.com  < /etc/hosts
foo@example.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
foo@example.com... Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this guide.

**[Configure sendmail for SMTP relay](http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0009.html)**

Answer (score 0):

try to configure sendmail to forward mails to your ISP's smtp server. Or install an smtp to your machine :>

Answer (score 0):

You could install nullmailer. It provides most of the sendmail parameters. It needs a second mailserver to relay the e-mails. The configuration ist *very* easy